# S-Bahn online ticket

Tags: munich, deutsche-bahn

I will be travelling to Germany for the first time for a concert. I'll be in Munich and I want to get from Hackerbrücke to Rosenheimer Platz. Is it possible to buy an online ticket the for S-Bahn from my phone? And if I buy it from my phone, do I need to print it or just scan it somewhere?
Also, how can I make sure I'm on the right train?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's an "MVV App" which allows that. I am not sure what payment option is best for you; but you can just download it and check if it has something that works for you.

You do not need to print or scan it, you just buy it at least a few minutes before the train goes and make sure you don't lose the Smartphone (or run out of battery...). There are no gates in the Munich transport system; there are very rare checks (by humans), and they will then just ask you to present the ticket on your smartphone. Note that it's usually necessary to buy your ticket *before* you enter the actual platform. There are signs for that (in German at least, can't remember if they're in english, but then it's also pretty obvious by the way everything is structured).

That said, getting the ticket from one of the vending machines is probably easier for you. Get a [day ticket](https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-and-fares/tickets-daytickets/single-day-ticket/index.html) ("Tageskarte") which gives you access to the inner district (which contains the stations you mentioned) for 6-7€ per day in 2018, which is likely less than you would pay if you get individual tickets for each single ride, if you go multiple times a day. And if you are more than one adult and stick together, then getting a [group day ticket](https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-and-fares/tickets-daytickets/group-day-ticket/index.html#c12527) is best.

Note that the MVV (city train network) tickets are very "light-weight", i.e. they are not personalized, are not directly fixed to a specific train, are not related to the regional/long-distance trains and so on.

Between Rosenheimer Platz and Hackerbrücke, *any* S-Bahn is the correct one as this is the completely linear part of the Munich S-Bahn. You only need to check the direction. If you look at the network plans hanging around everywhere, you will see that the central station is between those two stations. And at every platform, there will be signs that tell you whether you are standing on the side that goes in the direction of the city center (correct) or outwards (incorrect for you).

[image]

Comment: Is the MVV app equivalent to the DB Navigator app? If I buy a single ticket for a specific time and train and I miss that train, can I get on the next train and it's fine? Are the vending machines in English?

Comment: @Venoox yes, sure. It wasn't pointed out, so understand that the ticket is only valid for some hours after buying it - don't buy it now, it's not like a plane ticket. You need to buy it _right before you start your ride_.

Comment: @Venoox, MVV is the local city transport company. DB is the Germany-wide train provider. They work together of course, but if you're asking specifically about booking a MVV ticket, the MVV app is the straightforward thing to use. As Aganju said, those tickets are very "lightweight", compared to a long distance train.

Comment: @AnoE MVV is the local tariff system. ("Verbund")  The local (city) transport company is MVG, which also has an app which can be used to buy tickets as well.  (Note that MVV includes companies beyong MVG, such as DB and other bus/rail operators.)